# Make link enable and disable in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I Just want do opposite of this.Here is the working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KQQD2/4/

Means,first time links should be disable and unclickable, When I checked the checkbox I just want to make link enable and clickable.

Here is the code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $window){
        $scope.disableIt = false;
        $scope.tellAboutIt = function(){
            $window.alert('ngClick fired. This alert should not show when disabled.');
        };
    });

    app.directive('disableable', function($parse){
        return {
            restrict: 'C',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                scope.$watch('disableIt', function (val) {
                    if (!val) {
                        elem.addClass('disabled');
                        elem.css('cursor', 'default');
                        elem.bind('click', function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        elem.removeClass('disabled');
                        elem.css('cursor', 'pointer');
                        if (typeof elem.attr('ng-click') === 'undefined')
                           elem.unbind('click');
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you said was achieved by making

```
"disableIt || tellAboutIt()"
```

to

```
"disableIt && tellAboutIt()"
```

in the html part I found in jsFiddle.

Comment: Its not Working..As you can see in fiddle when we change it as "true",As you said.Its enabling the checkbox at first time,what I want is "When I checked the checkbox I just want to make link enable and clickable"

Comment: You mean that you want to change also the text to "ngClick enabled link"?

Comment: No,this is not what I want to achieve. What I want is,At first time checkbox should be unchecked and link should be disabled and unclickable also. And when checked box is checked I want to make links enable and clickable,thats it.

Comment: I opened the link you gave us and I found that the if(!val) is now if(val).
What you asked is working with  $scope.disableIt = false; and if(!val).

Comment: When I use if(!val),things working as I am expected, except clickable link..As you can see its alerting in the case when link is disable.And I want to make this happen in the case when link is enable.
Hope it may clear the things.

Comment: Your question didn't mention that.
The behavior you said was achieved by making "disableIt || tellAboutIt()" to "disableIt && tellAboutIt()" in the html part.

Comment: Yes you  are right..I haven't noticed that..thanks its working now as I am expected..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92273/discussion-between-v-maenolis-and-user5320720).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:
Given you have the value of the checkbox in your scope

```
$scope.data.checkValue = false
$scope.data.url = "http://foo.com"
```

And in your view:

```
<a ng-show="data.checkValue" href="data.url">bla</a>
<p ng-show="!data.checkValue">{{data.url}}</p>
```

Comment: I don't want to show/hide data.I just want to make link clickable or unclickable on the basis of checkbox value.

Comment: @user5320720 Then instead of `ng-show` try `ng-disabled`